# how to print lambda expression

Tags: python

I have two (many) lambdas:

```
myFoo = lambda x,y: x + y
mySpecFoo = lambda x: myFoo(x, 1)
```

I want to print resulting expression for mySpecFoo. smth like

```
x = var('x')
print(mySpecFoo(x))
```

and I want to see in output:

```
lambda x: x + 1
```

Do you know how to do this?
Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

This is called "symbolic evaluation", and you need some external library to do this, for example [SymPy](http://sympy.org/):

```
>>> import sympy
>>> myFoo = lambda x,y: x + y
>>> mySpecFoo = lambda x: myFoo(x, 1)
>>> x = sympy.var("x")
>>> print mySpecFoo(x) 
1 + x
```

Comment: thanks, Sage is cool but the shell for windows is still under dev :(